# Как лучше и проще пропарсить строку

Tags: c#, строки

Строки в файле записаны по следующему шаблону:
`"# MNEM.UNIT           VALUE                DESCRIPTION"`

Вот пример строк:

```
  STOP.M                       2054.30 : Конечная  глубина
  STEP.M                          0.10 : Шаг квантования по глубине
  NULL.                        -999.25 : Нулевое значение
```

Как проще и быстрей разобрать строку и получить следующее?

```
string MNEM = "STOP";
string UNIT = "M";
string VALUE = "2054.30";
string DESC = "Конечная глубина";
```

MNEM может в конце содержать пробел, но обязательно заканчивается на "."
UNIT не содержит пробелов.
VALUE может содержать и точки и пробелы

Comment: а чем Вас `split()` не устроил?!

Comment: linq - Не для разбора строк. здесь скорее регулярное выражение. а формат одинаковый? или строка может меняться?

Comment: @Bald56rus, Не всегда можно все разделители знать, например тут - в одном случае точка это разделитель, а в другом - нет

Comment: @Grundy в таком случае и регулярку составить не просто будет

Comment: Может быть такой `"DATE.DD.MM.YYYY                22.09.2015 : LOG DATE"`, а может и такой  `"SPS_ETL.                          в емк. с жидк : Способ эталонировки"`

Comment: @Bald56rus, зависит от формата

Comment: @МаксимКутовой, добавьте всю необходимую информацию в вопрос

Comment: Подправил вопрос.

Comment: а в случае последней строчки какой результат ожидается? UNIT - Это всегда один символ?

Comment: `string MNEM = "NULL"; // как текст`

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32712/discussion-between-grundy-and--).

Comment: А сам формат файлов можно изменить, чтобы был просто csv? Тогда можно было бы вот этой библиотекой воспользоваться https://github.com/mperdeck/LINQtoCSV

Comment: нельзя. Международный формат в определенной области =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

я бы cделал это так:

```
string s = "  STOP.M                       2054.30 : Конечная  глубина  ";
var _args = s.Split(new char[] { ':' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

if (_args.Count() != 2)
    throw new ArgumentException();

var DESCRIPTION = _args[1];

var MNEM = _args[0].Substring(0, _args[0].IndexOf("."));

var args1 = _args[0].Substring(MNEM.Length).Trim();

var UNIT = args1.Substring(0, args1.IndexOf(" "));

var VALUE = args1.Substring(UNIT.Length).Trim();
```

вроде данный код походит под описанный Вами формат

Comment: не под все случаи :-)

Comment: @Grundy а полностью универсального решения и не получиться сделать

Comment: @Bald56rus получилось же =)

Answer (score 3):

Вариант с регулярным выражением.
Собственно само выражение

```
^\s*(?<MNEM>\w+)\s*?\.(?<UNIT>[^\s]*?)\s+(?<VALUE>.+?)\s+?:\s*?(?<DESCRIPTION>.+)$
```

Пример использования:

```
var r = new Regex(@"^\s*(?<MNEM>\w+)\s*?\.(?<UNIT>[^\s]*?)\s+(?<VALUE>.+?)\s+?:\s*?(?<DESCRIPTION>.+)$");

var result = r.Match(i);// i - строка которую пытаетесь разбирать
```

`result.Groups["MNEM"].Value` - Значение попавшее в группу MNEM

`result.Groups["UNIT"].Value` - Значение попавшее в группу UNIT

`result.Groups["VALUE"].Value` - Значение попавшее в группу VALUE

`result.Groups["DESCRIPTION"].Value` - Значение попавшее в группу DESCRIPTION

---

^ начинает проверять с начала строки

\s* соответствует любому пробельному символу [\r\n\t\f ]

- Квантификатор: * подходит 0 или более совпадений [жадный]

(?<MNEM>\w+) Именованная группа MNEM

- \w+ соответствует буквенному символу [a-zA-Z0-9_]

  - Квантификатор: + подходит 1 или более совпадений [жадный]

\s* соответствует любому пробельному символу [\r\n\t\f ]

- Квантификатор: *? подходит 0 или более совпадений [ленивый]

\. соответствует символу "."

(?<UNIT>[^\s]*?) Именованная группа UNIT

- [^\s]*? соответствует одиночному символу не представленном в списке ниже

  - Квантификатор: *? подходит 0 или более совпадений [ленивый]
  - \s соответствует любому пробельному символу [\r\n\t\f ]

\s+ соответствует любому пробельному символу [\r\n\t\f ]

- Квантификатор: + подходит 1 или более совпадений [жадный]

(?<VALUE>.+?) Именованная группа VALUE

- .+? соответствует любому символу (кроме символов новой строки)

  - Квантификатор: +? подходит 1 или более совпадений [ленивый]

\s+? соответствует любому пробельному символу [\r\n\t\f ]

- Квантификатор: +? подходит 1 или более совпадений [ленивый]

: соответствует символу ":"

\s*? соответствует любому пробельному символу [\r\n\t\f ]

- Квантификатор: *? подходит 0 или более совпадений [ленивый]

(?<DESCRIPTION>.+) Именованная группа DESCRIPTION

- .+ соответствует любому символу (кроме символов новой строки)

  - Квантификатор: + подходит 1 или более совпадений [жадный]

$ указывает на конец строки

---

Жадный в данном случае отличается от ленивого тем, что ищет максимально длинную подходящую строку.

[Сервис с описанием](https://regex101.com/r/xD2dO6/1)

Comment: Шикарно, и спасибо за ссылочку